# How can we require a parameter in an ejs template such that ejs.render fails when the parameter is undefined?

Tags: ejs

I need to set the parameter so that if the parameter passed through to the template is undefined, the template rendering fails with an error.

Example template:

```
let template = "Hello <%=info.name%>, this is a test template.";
```

And when calling render, I send the following:

```
let data = {
    info: {
        name: "Bob"
    }
};
let rendered_template = ejs.render(template, data);
```

This gives the following value for rendered_template:

```
Hello Bob, this is a test template.
```

However, if `info.name` is undefined, then the template still gets rendered (it will only fail if `info` itself is undefined, because it won't be able to read property `name` of undefined), and the result is the following:

```
Hello , this is a test template.
```

How can I set the `info.name` parameter to be mandatory, so that ejs.render fails if the value of `info.name` is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `include` function in conjunction with an if/else block:

```
<% if (info.name != undefined) { %>
    <%- include 'someTemplate' %>
<% } %>
<% else { %>
    <%- include 'someOtherTemplate' %>
<% } %>
```

Where `someOtherTemplate` is the error page you want to render when `info.name` is undefined.

### Update

To send an error message with node.js, you can do something like this:

```
app.get('/someRoute', function(req, res) {
    if (info.name) {
      res.render('someTemplate', {info:info});
    }
    else {
      res.status(403);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a good approach, but unfortunately I don't think it fits my use case. I need to not send anything at all if it's undefined, so I want ejs to somehow throw me an error or stop the rendering. I think I can technically use this include approach and then check if the resulting template (from someOtherTemplate) is = "x" where "x" is some constant I define in `someOtherTemplate`, and then stop the execution after that. But it doesn't seem very clean to me.

Comment: What error message do you want to send, and what server language are you using?  I don't think you can do this with ejs, but you can definitely do it server side.

Comment: Any error works, I'm using Node.js and running this render call there. As I mentioned in the previous comment I can check the template and throw an error like that, but it doesn't seem like a clean approach. It's unfortunate there's no way to require a specific parameter

Comment: @Deiv there is a way to "require" a specific parameter...  Use an if/else block!